# dlply syntax with t.test

Tags: r, plyr

I clearly still don't understand plyr syntax, as illustrated below. Can someone help me see what I'm missing?

The following code works fine, as expected:

```
# make a data frame to use dlply on 
f <- as.factor(c(rep("a", 3), rep("b", 3)))
y <- rnorm(6)
df <- data.frame(f=f, y=y)

# split the data frame by the factor and perform t-tests
l <- dlply(df, .(f), function(d) t.test(y, mu=0))
```

However, the following causes an error

```
l_bad <- dlply(df, .(f), t.test, .mu=0)
Error in if (stderr < 10 * .Machine$double.eps * abs(mx)) stop("data are essentially constant") : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Which looks a bit as if R is trying to perform a t.test on the factor. Why would that be? Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dlply` splits `df` into several data frames. That means that whatever function you hand off to `dply` *must expect a data frame as input*. `t.test` expects a vector as it's first argument.

Your anonymous function in  `dlply` declares `d` as its only argument. But then in your call to `t.test` you pass only `y`. R doesn't automatically know to look *in the data frame d* for `y`. So instead it's probably finding the `y` that you defined in the global environment.

Simply changing that to `t.test(d$y,mu = 0)` in your first example should make it work.

The second example will only work if the function to be applied is expecting a data frame as input. (i.e. see `summarise` or `transform`.)